# Can BS player be installed on Mate?

Tags: vlc, alternative

So, can BS player be installed on Mate 18.04 as alternative to VLC player? You know, in Windows those two worked differently, as sub-searchers, in particular. Thanks, Igor

Comment: Post a link to the BS player home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. It is a windows application. WineHQ has a [garbage](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1072) rating so the only option is through virtualization (VirtualBox or VM Player).

> as sub-searchers

VLC nowadays uses the VLSub extension as an integral part of VLC ("View", "VLSub/Download Subtitles").